# Como filtrar por fecha desde y hasta en react js usando chart js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

Lo que ocurre es que estoy llenando un chart con datos a traves de un api. De ese endpoint yo saco dos datos para filtrar los cuales son la fecha inicial y la fecha final. Estoy intentando filtrar los datos de esta forma pero no funciona. Me podrian ayudar?

Esta seria la funcion:

```
chart = () => {
if(this.state.fechaIn === '' && this.state.fechaFin ==='' ){
this.setState({
  chartData: {
    labels: this.state.periodo,

    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Valor",
        data: this.state.mediciones.map((indicador) => indicador.Valor),
        backgroundColor: ["rgba(75,192,192,0.6)"],
        borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
        borderWidth: 1,
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0,
      },
      {
        label: "Meta",
        data: this.state.mediciones.map((indicador) => indicador.Meta),
        backgroundColor: ["rgba(75,192,192,0.6)"],
        borderColor: "rgba(33, 136, 55)",
        borderWidth: 1,
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0,
        pointRadius: 0,
      },
      {
        label: "Limite superior",
        data: this.state.mediciones.map(
          (indicador) => indicador.LimiteSuperior
        ),
        backgroundColor: ["rgba(75,192,192,0.6)"],
        borderColor: "rgba(220, 53, 69)",
        borderWidth: 1,
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0,
        pointRadius: 0,
      },
      {
        label: "Limite inferior",
        data: this.state.mediciones.map(
          (indicador) => indicador.LimiteInferior
        ),
        backgroundColor: ["rgba(75,192,192,0.6)"],
        borderColor: "rgba(220, 53, 69)",
        borderWidth: 1,
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0,
        pointRadius: 0,
      },
      {
        label: "Limite Cont. Inferior",
        data: this.state.mediciones.map(
          (indicador) => indicador.LimiteControlInferior
        ),
        backgroundColor: ["rgba(75,192,192,0.6)"],
        borderColor: "rgba(255, 193, 7)",
        borderWidth: 1,
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0,
        pointRadius: 0,
      },
      {
        label: "Limite Cont. Superior",
        data: this.state.mediciones.map(
          (indicador) => indicador.LimiteControlSuperior
        ),
        backgroundColor: ["rgba(75,192,192,0.6)"],
        borderColor: "rgba(255, 193, 7)",
        borderWidth: 1,
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0,
        pointRadius: 0,
      },
    ],
  },
});
        } else{
  
this.setState({
  chartData: {
    labels: this.state.mediciones.filter(indicador => this.state.fechaIn >= Date.parse(indicador.Periodo.FechaInicial.slice(0, -9)) ||  this.state.fechaFin <= Date.parse(indicador.Periodo.FechaFinal.slice(0, -9)))
    .map((indicador) => indicador.Periodo.PeriodoCodigo),

    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Valor",
        data: this.state.mediciones.filter((indicador) => this.state.fechaIn >= Date.parse(indicador.Periodo.FechaInicial.slice(0, -9)) ||  this.state.fechaFin <= Date.parse(indicador.Periodo.FechaFinal.slice(0, -9)))
        .map((indicador) => indicador.Valor),
        backgroundColor: ["rgba(75,192,192,0.6)"],
        borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
        borderWidth: 1,
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0,
      },
      {
        label: "Meta",
        data: this.state.mediciones.filter((indicador) => this.state.fechaIn >= Date.parse(indicador.Periodo.FechaInicial.slice(0, -9)) ||  this.state.fechaFin <= Date.parse(indicador.Periodo.FechaFinal.slice(0, -9))).map((indicador) => indicador.Meta),
        backgroundColor: ["rgba(75,192,192,0.6)"],
        borderColor: "rgba(33, 136, 55)",
        borderWidth: 1,
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0,
        pointRadius: 0,
      },
      {
        label: "Limite superior",
        data: this.state.mediciones.filter((indicador) => this.state.fechaIn >= Date.parse(indicador.Periodo.FechaInicial.slice(0, -9)) ||  this.state.fechaFin <= Date.parse(indicador.Periodo.FechaFinal.slice(0, -9))).map(
          (indicador) => indicador.LimiteSuperior
        ),
        backgroundColor: ["rgba(75,192,192,0.6)"],
        borderColor: "rgba(220, 53, 69)",
        borderWidth: 1,
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0,
        pointRadius: 0,
      },
      {
        label: "Limite inferior",
        data: this.state.mediciones.filter((indicador) => this.state.fechaIn >= Date.parse(indicador.Periodo.FechaInicial.slice(0, -9)) ||  this.state.fechaFin <= Date.parse(indicador.Periodo.FechaFinal.slice(0, -9))).map(
          (indicador) => indicador.LimiteInferior
        ),
        backgroundColor: ["rgba(75,192,192,0.6)"],
        borderColor: "rgba(220, 53, 69)",
        borderWidth: 1,
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0,
        pointRadius: 0,
      },
      {
        label: "Limite Cont. Inferior",
        data: this.state.mediciones.filter((indicador) => this.state.fechaIn >= Date.parse(indicador.Periodo.FechaInicial.slice(0, -9)) ||  this.state.fechaFin <= Date.parse(indicador.Periodo.FechaFinal.slice(0, -9))).map(
          (indicador) => indicador.LimiteControlInferior
        ),
        backgroundColor: ["rgba(75,192,192,0.6)"],
        borderColor: "rgba(255, 193, 7)",
        borderWidth: 1,
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0,
        pointRadius: 0,
      },
      {
        label: "Limite Cont. Superior",
        data: this.state.mediciones.filter((indicador) => this.state.fechaIn >= Date.parse(indicador.Periodo.FechaInicial.slice(0, -9)) ||  this.state.fechaFin <= Date.parse(indicador.Periodo.FechaFinal.slice(0, -9))).map(
          (indicador) => indicador.LimiteControlSuperior
        ),
        backgroundColor: ["rgba(75,192,192,0.6)"],
        borderColor: "rgba(255, 193, 7)",
        borderWidth: 1,
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0,
        pointRadius: 0,
      },
    ],
  },
});

 /* this.addData();  */
  }
   };
```

Lei la documentacion de chart js donde dice que para actualizar debia usar update en la cual use estas dos funciones con otro state llamado chartFilter pero tampoco me funcionaba ya que me decia que el chart no es una funcion.

```
   removeData = () =>{
    this.state.chartData.labels.pop();
    this.state.chartData.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.pop();
    });
    this.state.chartData.update();
  }

  addData = () =>{

    this.removeData();


    this.state.chartData.labels.push(this.chartFilter.labels);
    this.state.chartData.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push(this.chartFilter.dataset.data);
    });
    this.state.chartData.update();
  }
```

Comment: Un filtrado de datos debería hacerse del lado del servidor, de donde obtienes la data?

Comment: la obtengo de un endpoint llamado mediciones de ahi salen todos los datos.

Comment: Por qué mejor no envías la fecha de inicio y fecha de fin a ese endpoint y haces el filtro allí? Para que el chart sólo se encargue de dibujar el gráfico.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que ese endpoint solo recibe un parametro y es el id del indicador (bueno ya eso hace parte de la logica) que estoy revisando en el momento, a diferencia de otros endpoints que me dieron que si se pueden filtrar con parametros. :c

Comment: Debes hacerlo de esa manera, es más eficiente. De lo contrario siempre tendrás que cargar toda la data y hacer el filtro recién en React. Imagina que sólo quieres revisar la data de una semana, y tienes data de 2 años en tu bd, pero como no hay filtros en el endpoint, siempre te retornará todo lo de hace 2 años y tú recién harás el filtro en el front. Eso no es eficiente.

Comment: Si tal vez sea lo mas eficiente pero me lo han pedido de esta forma por el momento :/. No hay forma de filtrar por fechas a traves de React Js?